nginx 502 badgateway shows on opening my hosted site developed using nodejs,also on lodding pm2 shows App is not defined
on logging pm2 error shows /home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/plantly-error.log last 15 lines:
0|plantly  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
0|plantly  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
0|plantly  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
0|plantly  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
0|plantly  | ReferenceError: app is not defined
0|plantly  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/index.js:1:1)
0|plantly  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
0|plantly  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
0|plantly  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
0|plantly  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
0|plantly  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
0|plantly  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
0|plantly  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
0|plantly  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
0|plantly  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)

how to solve
I was expecting as error free,due this when I 'm trying to get my site,it shows 502 bad gateway,why

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please also include the code.  You either have not defined app or you loaded it incorrectly...  or a lot of other reasons.  This is why aside for the traceback, you need to include more context (as in an explanation of what you are doing,  what you're expecting to see and the code you're using.)
